# Spurious "Having trouble accessing" private beta email

Tags: bug, status-completed, area-51, private-beta

I just got an email from Area 51 titled "Having trouble accessing Board and Card Games? - Area 51 - Stack Exchange" dealing with its private beta.

It starts with
"Are you having trouble accessing the Board and Card Games private beta you committed to? We haven't seen you around!"

The thing is, it has [seen me around](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/users/87/powerlord).  On four different days, including the last three consecutive days, from an account [linked to my Area 51 account](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/users/87?tab=accounts).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Oops, sorry about that!

We recently updated Area 51 to only keep track of [beta users with >= 200 rep](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/5220?phase=beta&users=reputation#tab-top), but failed to realize that this change broke our logic for sending out the "having trouble accessing" emails.

We'll make sure this is fixed in time for the next beta. Thanks for the report.